# How to change transparency in geom_flow ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha-transparency, geom

I am trying to change the transparency of the flow elements of an alluvial plot. I know I should change the value of 'alpha' but I am not sure where in the code I have to add this parameter. The following is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)

ggplot(sp.alluvial, aes(x = stage, stratum = state, alluvium = pks, fill = state, label = state)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set2") +
  geom_flow(stat = "alluvium", lode.guidance = "frontback", aes(fill = state), aes.flow = "backward") + 
  geom_stratum() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

I have tried the next options:

```
geom_flow(stat = "alluvium", lode.guidance = "frontback", aes(fill = state), aes.flow = "backward", alpha = 0.6)

geom_flow(stat = "alluvium", lode.guidance = "frontback", aes(fill = state, alpha = 0.6), aes.flow = "backward")
```

and

```
+ geom_density(alpha = 0.6)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work.
The plot is based on the second example in [`geom_lode`](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/ggalluvial/html/geom_lode.html), since the question does not have a posted data set.

I have plotted the same with different values of the `alpha` argument, `0.2` and `0.8`, and the flows' transparency does change.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)

gg <- ggplot(as.data.frame(Titanic),
             aes(y = Freq, 
                 axis1 = Class, axis2 = Sex, axis3 = Age,
                 fill = Survived))

gg + 
  geom_flow(alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_stratum() + 
  geom_lode() + 
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", infer.label = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! it works, although I had to change transparency to 0.2 to see a difference because my dataset is very big (the input table has thousands of rows) and a smaller change in transparency was not making a clear difference as in smaller datasets.